# Fit MRI data to a noncentral chi distribution

Tags: matlab, histogram, data-fitting

I'm working on Magnetic Resonance Imaging data, on Matlab R2020a. In particular, i have to characterize the background noise of the image and i know it has a noncentral chi distribution. Now, i'm trying the mle method whitout results:

`[phat,pci] = mle(data,'pdf',@(data,v,d)ncx2pdf(data,v,d),'start',[1 1]);`

data is a row vector (1024,1), `v` are the dof of the distribution and `d` the noncentrality parameter (the two parameters that i have to find).
The problem lies in the fact that the distribution strongly depends on the value of the mean, and the order of magnitude of my data is 10^-6.

histogram of the data:

[image]

Does anyone know a method to fit the data to a noncentral chi distribution? I already tried the 0-1 and 0-255 normalization, but they produces unreliable mean values. Any suggestions are welcome.

[data.mat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GeoTTU3-YV4K7AwkX-zTkk9WiChu8SZP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Since you did not include any data, I made some normally distributed data that approximates your histogram.  I kept getting this error: The PDF function returned NaN or infinite values.  Here are my thoughts after playing with this for a while: 1) you say you know it has a non-central chi distribution, but I would have to disagree with you on that.  Look at the doc for ncx2pdf, your histogram does not match that shape, you could probably try a normal distribution.  2) Your initial guess (start argument) to mle is very important.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Kenneth. Data.mat vector is now included in the text. I think i figured out (at least) a part of the problem. I was trying to fit a nc-chi distribution with a nc-chisquare pdf. So, that was the mistake, i think. I squared the data and something changed. But, now it works just if i specify one of the parameters (d, the noncentrality coefficient) and it's not be able to estimate both. Any suggestion?